# Unable to create same TCP message with C# and C++

Tags: c#, c++, boost-asio, flatbuffers

I want to create same message and send it with C# as I do it with C++ where all works. Note that I have C# client where I have troubles, C++ client where all works fine and C++ server that should read messages from both C# and C++ clients.

Here is how I send the message from C++:

```
void ConnectAuthserverCommand::SendLogin(tcp::socket &s, const flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder &builder) const {

    ClientOpcode opc = CLIENT_LOGIN_REQUEST;
    flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder builder2;

    auto email = builder2.CreateString("test@abv.bg");
    auto password = builder2.CreateString("test");
    auto loginRequest = Vibranium::CreateLoginRequest(builder2, email, password);
    builder2.FinishSizePrefixed(loginRequest);
    size_t size2 = builder2.GetSize();
    uint8_t *buf2 = builder2.GetBufferPointer();

    uint8_t *actualBuffer2 = new uint8_t[size2 + 2];
    actualBuffer2[1] = (opc >> 8);
    actualBuffer2[0] = (opc&0xFF);
    memcpy(actualBuffer2 + 2, buf2, size2);

    boost::asio::write(s, boost::asio::buffer(actualBuffer2,size));
}
```

`ClientOpcode` is as follows:

```
enum ClientOpcode : uint16_t{
    CLIENT_AUTH_CONNECTION                            = 0x001,
    CLIENT_LOGIN_REQUEST                              = 0x002,
    CLIENT_NUM_MSG_TYPES                              = 0x003,
};
```

What I do is the following: I get a `ClientOpcode` which I want to put infront of `FlatBuffers` message. So I create an array of `uint8_t` which I extend with exactly 2 bytes(Because the size of `uint16_t` is 2 bytes.) Than on the server I read the first 2 bytes in order to get the header and here is how I do that:

```
void Vibranium::Client::read_header() {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    _packet.header_buffer.resize(_packet.header_size);
    boost::asio::async_read(socket,
    boost::asio::buffer(_packet.header_buffer.data(), _packet.header_size),
    [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec,std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        if ((boost::asio::error::eof == ec) || (boost::asio::error::connection_reset == ec))
        {
            Disconnect();
        }
        else
        {
            assert(_packet.header_buffer.size() >= sizeof(_packet.headerCode));
            std::memcpy(&_packet.headerCode, &_packet.header_buffer[0], sizeof (_packet.headerCode));
            if(_packet.headerCode)
                read_size();
            else
                Logger::Log("UNKNOWN HEADER CODE", Logger::FatalError);

        }
    });
}
```

So far so good, however I am not able to send correctly formatted same message from the C# client. Note that I send exactly same data, take a look:

```
Client authClient = GameObject.Find("Client").GetComponent<AuthClient>().client; // This is how I get Client class instance.
ClientOpcode clientOpcode = ClientOpcode.CLIENT_LOGIN_REQUEST;
var builder = new FlatBuffers.FlatBufferBuilder(1);
var email = builder.CreateString("test@abv.bg");
var password = builder.CreateString("test");
var loginRequest = LoginRequest.CreateLoginRequest(builder, email, password);
builder.FinishSizePrefixed(loginRequest.Value);
authClient.Send(builder, clientOpcode);
```

And here is how I actually prepend the header and send the data in C#:

```
public static Byte[] PrependClientOpcode(FlatBufferBuilder byteBuffer, ClientOpcode code)
{
    var originalArray = byteBuffer.SizedByteArray();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[originalArray.Length + 2];
    buffer[1] = (byte)((ushort)code / 0x0100);
    buffer[0] = (byte)code;
    Array.Copy(originalArray, 0, buffer, 2, originalArray.Length);
    return buffer;
}

public void Send(FlatBufferBuilder builder, ClientOpcode opcode)
{
    byte[] buffer = builder.SizedByteArray();

    var bufferToSend = PrependClientOpcode(builder, opcode);
    if (bufferToSend.Length > MaxMessageSize)
    {
        Logger.LogError("Client.Send: message too big: " + bufferToSend.Length + ". Limit: " + MaxMessageSize);
        return;
    }


    if (Connected)
    {
        // respect max message size to avoid allocation attacks.
        if (bufferToSend.Length <= MaxMessageSize)
        {
            // add to send queue and return immediately.
            // calling Send here would be blocking (sometimes for long times
            // if other side lags or wire was disconnected)
            sendQueue.Enqueue(bufferToSend);
            
            sendPending.Set(); // interrupt SendThread WaitOne()
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Logger.LogWarning("Client.Send: not connected!");
    }
}
```

`ClientOpcode` enum on C# is as follows:

```
public enum ClientOpcode : ushort
{
    CLIENT_AUTH_CONNECTION                            = 0x001,
    CLIENT_LOGIN_REQUEST                              = 0x002,
    CLIENT_NUM_MSG_TYPES                              = 0x003,
}
```

I think I can use `ushort` as a replacement of `uint16_t` in C#. That is why ClientOpcode is ushort.

When I send the message I get error on the client saying `UNKNOWN HEADER CODE`. If you take a look at the C++ server code to read the header you'll see that this message is displayed when the server is unable to read the header code. So somehow I am unable to place the `ClientOpcode` header correctly infront of the TCP message send from the C# client.

In order to find out what are the differences I installed WireShark on the host to track both messages. Here are they:

This one is from the correctly working C++ client:

[image]

And this one is the dump of the C# client:

[image]

As you can see on the second image of the TCP dump the Length of is bigger. C++ message is with length of `58` where C# message's length is `62`. Why?

The C++ client is sending data:

```
0200340000000c00000008000c00040008000800000014000000040000000400000074657374000000000b00000074657374406162762e626700
```

When the C# client is sending:

```
0000003a0200340000000c00000008000c00040008000800000014000000040000000400000074657374000000000b00000074657374406162762e626700
```

The C# client is adding to it's message in front `0000003a`. If I remove that messages should be the same and all will work.

Why is my C# client adding those extra data in front and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you cannot use a union of various opcodes in the flatbuffer schema? Seems cleaner than prefixing an opcode type by hand.

Comment: @Botje I would like to achieve it first by hand. About the Unions of FlatBuffer I am not exactly sure for what they serve?

Comment: According to [the flatbuffers documentation](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_writing_schema.html) you should be able to define `Union Op { AuthConnection, LoginRequest }` and see which variant the message contains.

Comment: You didn't show how you actually send that message. Suspicious that 3a is 58, which is the length of the message...

Comment: Check the length of `bufferToSend`... it probably does not contain those extra four bytes.  So investigate the code that dequeues from `sendQueue`, which you have not shown.

Comment: @Evk I send the message like this, please take a look: https://github.com/vis2k/Telepathy/blob/master/Telepathy/Client.cs . I use Telepathy to send message over TCP with C#. Can you check it out ?

Comment: @BenVoigt  please check how I send the actual TCP message here: https://github.com/vis2k/Telepathy/blob/master/Telepathy/Client.cs I use Telepathy to send message over TCP with C#.

Comment: Well you've got a problem, because [Telepathy puts into own length prefix on the data you give it.](https://github.com/vis2k/Telepathy/blob/1c1cdd92ff7a1e55f8c3a0668c40255639fc8804/Telepathy/Common.cs#L66)  It appears that Telepathy client is designed to talk to a Telepathy server and not an arbitrary TCP connection.

Comment: Here: https://github.com/vis2k/Telepathy/blob/1c1cdd92ff7a1e55f8c3a0668c40255639fc8804/Telepathy/Common.cs#L89 you prepend 4 bytes with message length

Comment: @Evk still does not work even I delete the whole for loop where it is adding the header. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Note also `packetSize += sizeof(int) + messages[i].Length;` above that loop.

Comment: this `sizeof(int)` should be removed ? Am I right ?

Comment: Yes sure, I guess you should be able to fix the problem yourself now.